# How can I create a function to get a date-time subset of a second dataframe?

Tags: r, date, subset, tidyverse

I'm trying to write code to partially automate the process of subsetting a temperature dataset with start/end date-times in a winter mortality dataset, the latter having something over 100 observations, each of which would end up with one such temp data subset.  I plan to calculate some temperature variables using each of these subsets, and add them to this second dataset.. but I'm hung up on the subsetting step.

Here's example data and my code (and let me know if you have suggestions on making this minimum reproducible.. I haven't posted here too much yet):

```
# Temperature data dput..
tempd <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("12/1/2014", "12/2/2014", "12/3/2014", "12/4/2014", "12/5/2014", "12/6/2014"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0:00:00", "12:00:00"), class = "factor"), temp = c(3.274, -0.986, -0.088, 0.495, 6.23, 0.934, 0.715, -4.227, -1.584, 0.88, 1.967)), .Names = c("date", "time", "temp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

# and mortality data dput..
owmd <- structure(list(siteyear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "s1.y1", class = "factor"), winter = c(1415L, 1415L, 1415L), date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("12/1/2014", "12/3/2014", "12/5/2014"), class = "factor"), site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "s1", class = "factor"), mort = c(0.06651485, 0.120592869, 0.135272089)), .Names = c("siteyear", "winter", "date", "site", "mort"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**EDIT:**
In case I've oversimplified my temp dataset, I'll say that my real temperature datasets (there are 10 of them, one for each site-year combination I have) contain values of temperature at 15 minute intervals (i.e. 96/day).  Importantly, I want these temp subsets to start and end at 12pm, so I need to be able to specify the time as well as the date at the subset limits (note the very first temp subset of the dataset might not be able to start at 12pm if the dataset itself begins at a later time)

So, the code..

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Factorize winter and 'date-ize' date 
owmd$winter <- as.factor(owmd$winter)
owmd$date <- as.Date(owmd$date, '%m/%d/%Y')

# Create start date (date value for the prior observation)
owmd %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(sdate = lag(date, 1)) -> owmd


# Now the temperature dataset

# Factorize date, do *something* with time, and create datetime
tempd$date2 <- as.Date(tempd$date, '%m/%d/%Y')
tempd %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hms('2014-12-01 12:00:00') + c(0:10) * hours(12), 
         time2 = parse_time(tempd$time)) -> tempd


# write a function that creates, for each observation in owmd, a subset of the tempd data bounded by owmd$date and owmd$sdate ('start date')
subfun <- function(x,y) {
  start <- owmd[(x-1),3]
  end <- owmd[x,3]
  period <- filter(y, date2 >= start & time2 >= '12:00:00' & date2 <= end & time2 <= '12:00:00')
}

# test it
subfun(3, tempd)
```

Finding the right subset conditions in `period` is where I'm hung up.  I'm getting

```
Warning messages:
1: In evalq((date2 >= start & time2 >= "12:00:00") & (date2 <= end &  :
  Incompatible methods (">=.Date", "Ops.data.frame") for ">="
2: In evalq((date2 >= start & time2 >= "12:00:00") & (date2 <= end &  :
  Incompatible methods ("<=.Date", "Ops.data.frame") for "<="
```

Seems like it shouldn't be too hard to use `owmd$date` and `owmd$sdate` (start date) as bounds for temperature dataset subsets, but I haven't managed to figure out the right subset conditions.  Would a different format for `tempd$time` help?  I include `temp$datetime` in case it could be used, but I didn't see how.

Any thoughts for a beginner are greatly appreciated.

Here's my session info:

> R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
>
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing reproducible data! There are a number of fixes that can help make this easier and more readable; below is how I would approach it. Essentially your goal is to figure out which temperature measurements fit each mortality period to do statistics on them. There's a few key realisations:

1. You want a function that accepts a dataframe, a column to put conditions on, and two conditions, but this is already what `dplyr::filter` does so we don't need another wrapper function really;
2. It would be helpful to keep the subsets with the corresponding mortality data and start/end dates so we should use a *list-column* to hold it;
3. We can concatenate `12:00:00` to the dates in `owmd` before parsing so that they are datetimes;
4. We can do a bunch of style changes (e.g. stick to `lubridate` parsers since you already use the package)

This means that I can do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
tempd <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("12/1/2014", "12/2/2014", "12/3/2014", "12/4/2014", "12/5/2014", "12/6/2014"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0:00:00", "12:00:00"), class = "factor"), temp = c(3.274, -0.986, -0.088, 0.495, 6.23, 0.934, 0.715, -4.227, -1.584, 0.88, 1.967)), .Names = c("date", "time", "temp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
owmd <- structure(list(siteyear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "s1.y1", class = "factor"), winter = c(1415L, 1415L, 1415L), date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("12/1/2014", "12/3/2014", "12/5/2014"), class = "factor"), site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "s1", class = "factor"), mort = c(0.06651485, 0.120592869, 0.135272089)), .Names = c("siteyear", "winter", "date", "site", "mort"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

mort <- owmd %>%
  mutate(
    winter = factor(winter),
    date = date %>% str_c(., " 12:00:00") %>% mdy_hms(),
    sdate = lag(date)
  )
temp <- tempd %>%
  mutate(datetime = str_c(date, " ", time) %>% mdy_hms(), date = mdy(date))

mort_subs <- mort %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    subset = map2(sdate, date, ~ filter(temp, datetime >= .x & datetime <= .y)
    )
  )
mort_subs
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   siteyear winter date                site    mort sdate              
#>   <fct>    <fct>  <dttm>              <fct>  <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-01 12:00:00 s1    0.0665 NA                 
#> 2 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-03 12:00:00 s1    0.121  2014-12-01 12:00:00
#> 3 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-05 12:00:00 s1    0.135  2014-12-03 12:00:00
#> # ... with 1 more variable: subset <list>
```

so now we have the right subset for each original row of `owmd`. Each element of the `subset` column contains a dataframe that is the subset of `temp` corresponding to the `sdate` and `date`. The tidyverse has a lot of tools that let us work with this data easily; we can `unnest`, `group_by` and `summarise` to get a statistic per original row:

```r
mort_subs %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(siteyear, winter, sdate, date, site, mort) %>%
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temp))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#> # Groups:   siteyear, winter, sdate, date, site [?]
#>   siteyear winter sdate               date                site   mort
#>   <fct>    <fct>  <dttm>              <dttm>              <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-01 12:00:00 2014-12-03 12:00:00 s1    0.121
#> 2 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-03 12:00:00 2014-12-05 12:00:00 s1    0.135
#> # ... with 1 more variable: mean_temp <dbl>
```

Or we can accomplish a similar thing by using `map_dbl` to iterate over the `subset` list-column:

```r
mort_subs %>%
  mutate(mean_temp = map_dbl(subset, ~ mean(.$temp)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   siteyear winter date                site    mort sdate              
#>   <fct>    <fct>  <dttm>              <fct>  <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-01 12:00:00 s1    0.0665 NA                 
#> 2 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-03 12:00:00 s1    0.121  2014-12-01 12:00:00
#> 3 s1.y1    1415   2014-12-05 12:00:00 s1    0.135  2014-12-03 12:00:00
#> # ... with 2 more variables: subset <list>, mean_temp <dbl>
```

Created on 2018-10-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Calum, thank you for so thoroughly addressing my dilemma and offering suggestions on improving my code. I tried the map2 solution unsuccessfully.. and realize that I may not have given you enough information about my 'real' temperature dataset, and my requirements for subset limits (i.e., I need to be able to specify the time as well, if possible). I've added an edit above that hopefully clarifies this. If you have additional input in light of this, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Ah, now I see that using your approach I did create a list of dataframes (took a little looking around at my output to realize that).  Now I just need to be able to specify the times of the limits.

Comment: Updated to what i think you want; i.e set the bounds of the sdate and date to be noon on those dates instead of midnight.

Comment: Thanks Calum.. I'd just figured that out!  Now I just have to try out the last step (unnesting, etc.)..

Comment: It took me a little while to get through this, because my real data and temperature variables were quite a bit more complicated, but I think I've got it.  Many thanks, Calum.